# UIScrollView paging requires manual Edge Inset modifications to work correctly

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a uiscrollview containing three uiviewcontrollers with paging enabled. When content inset is {0, 0, 0, 0}, this is the result:

[image]

But when I modify the content inset of the scrollview to have -7 for the left, this is fixes it: 
[image]

I'm trying to figure out why is -7 the magic number to fix this?
Here's the code for the SliderViewController

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil event:(Event*)event
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _event = event;
         conversationVC = [[ConversationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConversationViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] event:_event];
        eventVC = [[EventControlViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventControlViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        suggestionVC = [[SuggestionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SuggestionViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self addChildViewController:conversationVC];
        [self addChildViewController:eventVC];
        [self addChildViewController:suggestionVC];
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
    CGFloat yMax = 0;
    for(UIView *view in _scrollView.subviews)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = curXLoc;
        view.frame = frame;
        curXLoc += view.frame.size.width;
        yMax = MAX(view.frame.size.height, yMax);
    }
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollView.subviews.count * 320, yMax)];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    [_scrollView addSubview:conversationVC.view];
    [_scrollView addSubview:eventVC.view];
    [_scrollView addSubview:suggestionVC.view];
    [self layoutSubviews];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u initiate the view controllers from storyboard, just open the Size Inspector to check the x of your root view's frame rectangle is set to 0

Comment: I'm not using storyboard (supporting iOS 4.2).

Comment: Where is your scroll view initiate code? The width of each page is depend on the scroll view's frame width. So there is two possibilities. The one is u want a 14px(28px on retina display) width space between all pages, so u set the scroll view's frame width to "[[UIScreen mainwindow] bounds].frame.with + 7*2" but forgot to set the frame's x origin -7 to center the scroll view. To fix it, just set the scroll view's frame's x origin -7. And the other one is u want the same effect but you set the contentInset. I'm not sure this could make it. But Apple just recommended the way I described before.

Comment: My scroll view code is initialized by the Interface Builder. I've set the scroll view's frame width to 320 and the origin.x is at 0. The all subviews for the scroll view have a width of 320 with the origin.x shifted at 320*pagenumber for each subview. I don't believe I have anything that would add 14px width between the pages.